# How do we tag Terraria versions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Terraria is out for the PC, Xbox 360, PS3, and Android and iOS devices. As far as I can tell, the Xbox 360 and PS3 versions have little to no difference as seems to be with Android and iOS versions. (Someone who actually owns the games on those devices will need to confirm.)

But the thing is that PC version is quite different from the console versions, and the console versions seem vastly different from the mobile versions.

I think we need something to tell them apart. How do we tag the different versions of Terraria?

Comment: Related: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7084/how-should-we-tag-the-xbox-360-and-ps3-versions-of-terraria

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[terraria](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraria) <- [terraria-pc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraria-pc) ✓

[terraria-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraria-console) <- [terraria-xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraria-xbox), [terraria-ps3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraria-ps3)

[terraria-mobile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraria-mobile) <- [terraria-ios](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraria-ios), [terraria-android](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraria-android)

Comment: [tag:terraria] ← [tag:terraria-pc] now exists.

Comment: @badp Great :D Just wasn't sure which direction we're gonna pick on that.

Comment: I suggest we also make [[tag:terraria-ios]] and [[tag:terraria-android]] synonyms of [[tag:terraria-mobile]], else it will never get used by new askers. Ditto [[tag:terraria-ps3]] and [[tag:terraria-xbox]] for [[tag:terraria-console]].