# Tagging Minecraft for consoles

Tags: discussion, tags, minecraft

Minecraft is currently available on XBox 360 and PS3, and is coming to the XBox One and PS4 sometime in the not so distant future.  Now I don't know how similar the code bases will be, but [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/147407/1351) seems to indicate that the crafting interface is the same at the very least.

Should we have multiple tags, or consolidate them into something like [minecraft-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-console)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mostly, just like how [we're doing it for Terraria](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7946/):

[minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) <- [minecraft-pc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pc)

[minecraft-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-console) <- [minecraft-ps3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-ps3), [minecraft-xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-xbox)

[minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition) <- [minecraft-mobile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mobile)

([minecraft-mobile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mobile) added purely for consistency)

---

[minecraft-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-console) could (if there are great differences between the generations) be split by generation. But at this point that would be pure speculation - and we would have to do the very same for a bunch of other cross-generation games.

Comment: What about [Minecraft Pi Edition](http://pi.minecraft.net)?

Answer (score 3):

Following updates and consolidation of the Minecraft versions by Mojang as part of the [Better Together' Update](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Better_Together_Update), our community [followed suit](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14846/28182) with our tagging efforts.

As such, the following tags should be used for console versions of Minecraft:

- [minecraft-legacy-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-legacy-console) - for older Minecraft console versions that are no longer supported by Mojang or it's affiliated developers.

  > Minecraft for Xbox 360, PS3, PS Vita, Wii U, and the old (non-Bedrock) editions for Xbox One and PS4.
  > <sub>See [Legacy Console Edition](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Legacy_Console_Edition) on the Minecraft Wiki for more information.</sub>
- [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition)  - for the multi-platform family of Minecraft editions that all now share a single code base. These versions are all officially just named 'Minecraft'.

  > Minecraft for Windows 10, Xbox One, PlayStation 4, Nintendo Switch, Gear VR, Apple TV, Fire TV and Mobile/Tablet devices (née 'Pocket Edition'): Android, iOS, Fire OS, Windows 10 Mobile
  > <sub>See [Bedrock Edition](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Bedrock_Edition) on the Minecraft Wiki for more information.</sub>