# Should we merge [minecraft-wii-u] with [minecraft-console]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request

Instead of having a different Minecraft tag for each gaming console, we [previously merged](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8124/28182) them into [minecraft-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-console).

I've just come across [minecraft-wii-u](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-wii-u). Should this also be merged into [minecraft-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-console)?

Comment: I believe it originally received its own tag because it was a completely different version from the XBox and Playstation versions.

Comment: @MBraedley - Ah fair enough. If that's the case then it should probably stay

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)!

This answer reached 5 votes with no downvotes, so I went ahead and edited all questions with the tag. Out of the 8 questions, 7 were specifically about the Wii U edition (and not general MC questions) so I added [wii-u](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wii-u) as well.

---

According to the [Minecraft Wiki article on console version history](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Console_Edition_version_history), Minecraft Wii U edition is up to date with the other console versions as of Patch 3 (Feb 26 2016).

Since the Wii U edition is the same as the other console versions, it should be merged into [minecraft-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-console).

It only has 8 questions, so if the community agrees I will retag the questions manually.

Comment: Cool. Well let's give it a couple of days and if there are no dissenting voices we can do it :-)

Comment: @Robotnik I'll leave a message in the bridge to gain attention.

Comment: So, despite any initial differences that may have called for a seperate tag, the wii-u version is now the same as the other console versions? Then I'd agree the tag is now superfluous.

Comment: @TrentHawkins It is now the same, yes.

Comment: Until the versions get out of sync again.  Good grief Minecraft needs a lot of maintenance here, lol