# What happened to the [terraria-console] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

[In the latest Meta discussion that I can find](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7946/how-do-we-tag-terraria-versions), consensus was reached to use the following tagging structure for the various flavors of Terraria:

> [terraria](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraria) <- [terraria-pc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraria-pc) ✓
>   [terraria-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraria-console) <- [terraria-xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraria-xbox), [terraria-ps3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraria-ps3)
>   [terraria-mobile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraria-mobile) <- [terraria-ios](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraria-ios), [terraria-android](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraria-android)

However, today, there are zero questions tagged [terraria-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraria-console). We most certainly have had (and still do have) questions about the console-specific ports, and I'm positive that there have been plenty of questions that have used the console-specific tag in the past. On top of that, the wiki excerpt for the base [terraria](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraria) tag specifically denotes that tag is for the PC version only, due to the existence of the console- and mobile-specific tags.

This came up when I noticed that the original version of [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/176954/where-does-the-demo-end-on-xbox) was tagged with the PC-specific tag, and when I went to reassign it to the console tag, it didn't even show up in the autocomplete list because it has zero questions tagged with it. Since I didn't want to re-use a tag that had been deprecated intentionally for one reason or another, I added an [xbox-360](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-360) tag as a stopgap until I could figure out what was going on.

Did some bulk retagging operation happen that I missed? What happened to all of the existing questions tagged [terraria-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraria-console)? If something's changed, what's our current policy on tagging Terraria questions?

Comment: Terraria Console has some things specific to it (at least a boss) Don't know why it would've been mass-retagged or anything.

Comment: I can only find [two](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/120268/revisions) [questions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/150786/revisions) that had the tag removed, both coincidental.  There are a bunch of other console questions that are *(and always have been)* tagged with a specific console.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the research. I'd be pretty shocked if the tag had only ever been used twice before, but I can't rule it out. I've seen at least a handful of console-specific questions float by before, but I can't recall this far after the fact whether that was before or after the new tagging guidelines were decided upon.

Comment: At the very least, it sounds like some time spent sifting through the main tag's questions to look for incorrectly-tagged questions may be called for.

Comment: I think Terraria  iOS has unique features, but control scheme aside, weren't the features from the console versions brought over to Terria in 1.2 or something?

Comment: @BenBrocka not from what I can tell. I just started playing so have been browsing the wiki and other spots, and there are still console only enemies and such.

Comment: @BenBrocka Not all of them. A lot of the console features did arrive in 1.2, but there is still a boss and a whole tier of materials that is console only.

Comment: Huh, sounds like it should still exist then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no obvious explanations have surfaced, I've finally trawled the [terraria](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraria) questions list to pick out the most obvious console-specific questions and retagged them to [terraria-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraria-console). Additional sets of eyeballs probably wouldn't go amiss in case I missed some questions.

The tag wiki was also empty, so I submitted an update for that as well.